# What is the reason of using two sets of parentheses on object method call

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm currently learning and educating myself on javascript, i just found one simple code which is using this '()();' what is this called, didnt find much information about it, what is it and how it is used, here the code i found :

```js
  'use strict';
    let obj, method;
    
    obj = {
      go: function() { alert(this); }
    };
    
    obj.go();              
    
    (obj.go)();            
    
    (method = obj.go)();  
    
    (obj.go || obj.stop)();
```

sory english is not my mother language if some mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Used on their own, parenthesis are grouping operators. They group expressions to control the order or *precedence* of the evaluation. You can [read MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) about it.

```
// example                 // is the same as            

(obj.go)();                 obj.go();

(method = obj.go)();        method = obj.go; method();

(obj.go || obj.stop)();     // calling go or stop after assinging to a temp variable
```

Comment: Great answer. The last one about the "temp variable" is a bit sour. Internally, an reference already exists and one or the other is accessed, but a new variable is not defined.

Comment: @RandyCasburn its just helpful to think that it exists.

Comment: if you change this '(method = obj.go)();  
  
' into this 'method = obj.go();  
', the result changes from '[object Window]' to ' [object Object]' try urself

Comment: @walee i'm not sure i follow. `method = obj.go()` should put `undefined` in `method` since `go` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @DanielA.White -  I'll buy that its helpful - I'm too close to the guts of it I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

That piece of code is demonstrating how `this` is bound within a function execution content (in this case in `go`). It shows that simply putting parentheses around a method does not alter that behaviour: `this` is still bound to `obj`.

As soon as the parentheses surround an *expression* involving operator(s) the situation changes, and the method that *results* from the expression is called without a specific `this` binding: the default applies (`undefined`).

Another variant is the following:

```
(0,obj.go)();
```

Here the comma-operator kicks in, and so we are in the *expression* case: `this` is no longer bound to `obj` in the method call.

Answer (score 0):

It just controls the order of the execution. You could write everything like this too, to make it more clear:

```
// (obj.go)();
obj.go();

// (method = obj.go)();
method = obj.go;
method();

// (obj.go || obj.stop)();
var method = obj.go || obj.stop;
method();
```